# alert is coming first time when click delete link but second time alert not coming

Tags: mysql, jsp, spring-mvc

i am trying to delete row when click on confirm link,alert is first time when click on delete link but second time alert not coming... 
value getting deleted without alert

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<title>SRK Pvt Ltd.</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form:form method="get" action="">
        <%--   <h1>${message}</h1>
    Enter Name: <input id="tagsName"> --%>

        <a href="<c:url value="/helloWorld" />">Autocomplete</a>

        <center>
            Dear <strong>${user}</strong>, Welcome to DBA Page. <a
                href="<c:url value="/logout" />">Logout</a>
            <div style="color: teal; font-size: 30px">SRK Pvt Ltd.</div>

            <c:if test="${!empty employeeList}">
                <script>
                    function ConfirmDelete() {
                        var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
                        if (x)
                            return true;
                        else
                            return false;
                    }
                </script>
                <table border="1" bgcolor="black" width="600px">
                    <tr
                        style="background-color: teal; color: white; text-align: center;"
                        height="40px">

                        <td>First Name</td>
                        <td>Last Name</td>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td>Phone</td>
                        <td>Edit</td>
                        <td>Delete</td>
                    </tr>
                    <c:forEach items="${employeeList}" var="user">

                        <tr
                            style="background-color: white; color: black; text-align: center;"
                            height="30px">

                            <td><c:out value="${user.firstName}" /></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${user.lastName}" /></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${user.email}" /></td>
                            <td><c:out value="${user.phone}" /></td>
                            <td><a href="edit?id=${user.id} ">Edit</a></td>
                            <td><a href="delete?id=${user.id}"
                                Onclick="return ConfirmDelete();">Delete</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </table>
            </c:if>


            <a href="form">Click Here to add new User</a>
        </center>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

second time alert box not showing value getting deleted directly when click on delete link

Comment: Check the browser console for errors

Comment: No their is no errors..

Comment: value getting deleted directly without any errors..

Comment: works for me, have you tried an other browser ?

Comment: I tried but still facing same problem..